# .htaccess redirect from php to html files?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

'trying to create redirects from php (old files) to new html files (yes, this way).
How to make redirect from index.php to index.htlm files?

The scenario is the following:

```
http://domain.com/ -> http://domain.com/index.html
http://domain.com/index.php -> http://domain.com/index.html
http://domain.com/?l=ru -> http://domain.com/index.html
http://domain.com/?l= -> http://domain.com/index.html
http://domain.com/index.php?l=ru -> http://domain.com/index.html

http://domain.com/?l=en -> http://domain.com/index_e.html
http://domain.com/index.php?l=en  -> http://domain.com/index_e.html
```

Please, help and, please, explain why your code will work.
Thanx

Comment: **please, explain why your code will work** Care to show what you've tried first?

Comment: I used:
    RewriteEngine on
and tried to define
   RewriteRule(s)
Some worked, some not and 500 error accompanied the results.
(Shame, but nothing of value to show; I am not good at all in writing .htaccess instructons. I tried to use info from other posts on .htaccess redirect, but did not succeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)l=en($|&)
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ index_e.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ultimater!
If you have time, please, explain what your code does.

Comment: The RewriteCond pairs with the next RewriteRule. It checks the query string, meaning that which follows the `?` character in URLs. The exclamation mark means not. The `(^|&)l=en($|&)` is a regular expression. We don't want to match  something like `scroll=end` which contains `l=en`. So the `(^|&)` matches either the beginning of the string or an `&` character. The `($|&)` matches the end of the string or an `&` character. If the condition is true, we run the first RewriteRule followed by `[L]` which makes it the last rule to run and thus never reads the 2nd RewriteRule.

Comment: Super!
Clear and precise!
Thank you very much!
p.s. Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: The first RewriteRule's logic is it matches `^`, the string beginning, against the file path. followed by `/?` which is an optional slash to match both `domain.com` and `domain.com/`. Next is `(index\.php)?` which optionally matches `index.php`. Followed by `$` which means end of string. Thus preventing issues with matching requests all other files such as `/about.html` and rewriting it to the wrong page. Finally it rewrites to either index.html or index_e.html depending on whether our RewriteCond matched.

Comment: gonna copy your comments to share with friends tomorrow :)